# show Open Mapping Theorem using Banach Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: banach-spaces, open-map

**Open Mapping Theorem:** let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T : X \to Y$ be a linear surjective continuous map. Then $T$ is opened.

**Definition:** let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed spaces and let $T : X \to Y$ be a mapping. We say that $T$ is an isomorphism if it is continuous, opened and bijective.

**Banach Isomorphism Theorem:** let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T : X \to Y$ be a linear bijective continuous map. Then $T$ is isomorphism.

Is it possible to show the Open Mapping theorem using Banach Isomorphism theorem? I think not because the hypothesis from the second is more specific (where do we get the injectivity from?); in fact, the second one is a trivial corollary from the first one: if we take the hypothesis from the Banach Isomorphism theorem, using the Open Mapping theorem, we have that $T$ is is opened, it means if $T$ is furthermore bijective that $T^{- 1} : Y \to X$ is continuous.

Comment: What do you know about $X/\ker T$?

Comment: it is isomorphic to $T(X)$

Comment: Which in our context is $Y$. And what do you know about $\pi \colon X \to X/\ker T$?

Comment: Yes $T(X) = Y$ because of the surjectivity. And $\pi$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: Do you know anything about the topological properties of $\pi$?

Comment: If $T: X \to Y$ is any map, you get an induced injection $\overline{T}: X/\ker T \to Y: x + \ker T \mapsto Tx$ so you can safely assume that $T$ is injective to begin with.

Comment: with epimorphism I mean continuous and opened from $X$ to $\pi(X / \ker T)$. I do not know if it has more topological properties.

Comment: Those are the important ones. So $T = \overline{T} \circ \pi$ is the composition of two continuous and open maps ...

Comment: is it possible that $T$ is not injective? what can I do with $\overline{T} \circ \pi$?

Comment: do you mean that the composition of two open maps is an open map and therefore we deduce that $T$ is open? but where have we used banach isomorphism theorem?

Comment: That tells us that $\overline{T} \colon X/\ker T \to Y$ is an isomorphism (of topological vector spaces), hence open.